# set ttimeoutlen in bash vi-mode

Tags: bash

I'm using vim to write commands in bash, however the time taking for vim to change modes is too long.

When using vim in the command line, my `.vimrc` is not read. Instead, the setup is done via `.inputrc`

I tried to enter the below in my `.inputrc`:

```
set ttimeoutlen 2
```

But the variable is not found:

```bash
readline: ~/.inputrc: line 8: ttimeoutlen: unknown variable name
```

How can I decrease the amount that time takes to change modes when using vim in the terminal?

I'm using bash on WSL2.

Comment: In case you are trying to set a Vim-specific option `ttimeoutlen` via `.inputrc`, this is wrong, Vim does not read `.inputrc`. Is there any particular reason you don't want to use `.vimrc`?

Comment: @asa Is the question about vim-like mode builtin in Bash? In that case it's not `vim` and cannot be configured with ex-commands. For the list of commands, configuration and default key bindings in `.inputrc` read the part of [`man bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) about **Readline**.

Comment: The reason I can't use `.vimrc` is because I'm using Vim in the terminal. So when I start the terminal, .vimrc is not read. The question is about the functionality you enable when adding the line  `set -o vi` to your `.bashrc` (so I guess you could say it's a vim-like mode builtin in Bash).

Comment: When you start a terminal, `.vimrc` is not read because you don't run `vim`. `set -o vi` in Bash is not `vim`, it's simple vim emulation, and not a full emulation, just a minor one. No way to use ex-commands in it.

Comment: Try adding `set keyseq-timeout 1` to `.inputrc`.